# Web scraping Obsidian Published vaults

Tags: web-scraping, wget, httrack

I'm trying to download Obsidian public vaults like this: https://publish.obsidian.md/bryan-jenks/Z/INDEX

I would like to get in each folder all its .md (markdown) notes.

I have tried with Httrack and with wget without success, only some files are downloaded.

How should I do it?